# Split a string if it contains enter key or \n

Tags: c#

I have a multiline textbox.  I am entering recipe ingredients one by one in each line by using enter key.  I am saving this to database in a single field, but on display I need to split them to show them line by line.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: SQL should be able to handle \n. Which database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you display, have such code:

```
strValueFromDb.Split('\n').ToList().ForEach(line =>
{
    lbDisplay.Text += line + "<hr />";
});
```

This example will show each line followed by `<hr />` you can do whatever you want of course.

Comment: -1 for creation of many many temporary strings, and updating the screen needlessly for each line added.  Definitely take the property reference outside the delegate.  Using `string.Join` or `StringBuilder` would be even better.  Also, appending to existing text is probably not desirable.

Comment: @Ben this is just example showing how to use `line` I assumed he wasn't going to use it as-is anyway but thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 5):

No special effort should be needed.

If the user enters a multi-line string and you save it to the database like that, when you fetch it from the database again, it will still be a multi-line string.

Answer (score 1):

Can't your database handle '\n'? If not (?), then replace it with a 'placeholder' such as '::' and then swap it back to '\n' when displaying it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method of a string:

```
string[] lines = "Line 1\r\nLine2\r\nLine 3".Split(new string[] { Environment.Newline }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Environment.Newline`

```
txtRecipe.Text = "First line" + Environment.Newline + "Second line";
```